# page width is going over 100%

Tags: html, css

I have the following css for my website...

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 100%;
    color: #323232;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 60%;
}
html, body { height:100%;}
```

it is adding a horizontal scroll bar for some reason and i dont know why

here is a fiddle for the full css and html: http://jsfiddle.net/charliejsford/9MdSv/

any ideas?

Comment: remove the height in you html/body tag..

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove the margin on the `body` element:

```
body {
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 100%;
    color: #323232;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 60%;
    margin: 0
}
```

Here's an updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9MdSv/1/).

Comment: i think its the css for the menu. the submenu width is doing it but i dont think there is anything i can do about that. here is another fiddle of the menu: http://jsfiddle.net/charliejsford/ejhHN/

Comment: If you have a different question, please ask it on here. :)

Comment: its to do with the same question? the page width is still going over 100%, its just that its the menu doing it

Comment: Technically it's a different question. The original one did not mention your menu, and only provided a jsfiddle demo, that was corrected with my answer.

Answer (score 1):

you have to set a max-width as the example here

```
#trans-nav li ul {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    max-width: 260px;
    background: #EEEEEE;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0; 
}
```